# How to validate edit Text so it is only possible to enter valid email?

Tags: android

I a making an android application using eclipse. I have editText box to validate as an email. This editText is obviously in XML and the id of it is "editText1".
I found the answers how to validate email but my problem is: i don't know how to apply this to that "editText1" in my java code.

```
Below i present the code for email validation that i found:

   public final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
            "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
            "\\@" +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
            "(" +
            "\\." +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
            ")+"
        );

    private boolean checkEmail(String email) {
        return EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

When I paste this code into my java file i get the message:

"The method checkEmail(string) from the type MainActivity is never used locally"

Comment: That warning is pretty self-explanatory. It means you never called that method.

Comment: I am sorry but i am new to java. In that case how should i call it?

Comment: Copy-pasting code and then debugging it is not a good way to learn (though reading code is). And you might not wanna jump into Android before learning Java.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get a reference to your EditText

Something like this should work:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Then you can get the text from your EditText like this:

```
String str = et.getText().toString();
```

then you can call your validate method

```
if(checkEmail(str)){
  //email is valid
}
```

However based on the question you are asking and the manner in which you've asked it I can tell that you would probably benefit greatly from going back and studying plain java before you dive into android. And that once you've got java syntax down, you should really start with the examples and tutorials on the official Android Developer website, it covers a lot of the basics that you seem to be having trouble understanding.

And one last aside, "editText1" is not a very good name for your EditText, it doesn't explain anything about the object. Your code will be easier to work with if you strive to use more descriptive names for objects, perhaps "emailText" might be a better choice?

Comment: Thank You. I guess i will have to spend more time on java. I have changed object id to  "email". Thank you very much for your help.